# Setting the "allowUnreachableCode" TypeScript Compiler Option In Visual Studio 2015 Causes Error "JsErrorScriptException (0x3001)"

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, tsconfig

We're using TypeScript with Visual Studio 2015 (Update 2) for a pure HTML, JavaScript project (not ASP.Net) and need to turn off the 'allowUnreachableCode' option. It's quite common to temporarily put an early 'return' in code for debug purposes. Setting the 'allowUnreachableCode' complier option in tsconfig appears to properly turn off the unreachable code warning. But now were getting this 'VSTSC' error when compiling: **JsErrorScriptException (0x30001)**.

**TSCONFIG**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "watch": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": true
  }
}
```

**CODE**

```
let router = new Router();

router.start()

return;
```

... additional code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "watch": true,

I suspect this is the option that is actually throwing up.